# Asp.net Response.Redirect CLEAR /CHANGE Response.UrlReferer / HTTP_REFERER

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp.net application that i use for traffic tracking.

I get a incoming visitor from several source websites and redirect the visitor to the target website using **Response.Redirect(url);**

The problem is that currently the referer shown to the target website (after i redirect) is of the url of the source website and not my website.

how do i **clear/change the referer before using the Response.Redirect?**

This is my code of Default.aspx:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                try
                {

                    Response.Redirect(url);
                }
                catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException) { }
            }
        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the Request.UrlReferrer.

Are you doing the Response.Redirect from an ASPX page or a generic handler(ASHX)?

If you're doing it from an ASHX, your website may not be listed in the Referrer, but it should work from the ASPX page.

If it still doesn't work..you have 2 solutions:

1.Try adding a meta refresh tag to the header of your aspx page from the codebehind.

```
Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "0; url=http://targetsite.com");
```

2.. Add Javascript to your page from the codebehind

```
Page.RegisterStartupScript("myScript", "<script language=JavaScript>window.location = "http://targetsite.com";</script>");
```

Comment: i'm using a regular aspx page called default.aspx , but still the referer isn't changed to my website url. see code above